# Is it "visit to my country" or "visit my country"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct or are they both correct?

> End of this year, I've a plan to **visit** my country.

Or,

> End of this year, I've a plan to **visit to** my country.

Comment: You can *visit your country* or you can ***go on a** visit **to** your country*. But you can't *visit **to** your country*.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch it around:

> I plan a visit my country
> I plan a visit to my country

Now the second one is correct, the first one incorrect.

For the *to* examples, we have a verb phrase "to visit my country"; here "visit" is a verb and "my country" is its direct object.
For the *a* examples, we have a noun phrase "a visit to my country"; here "visit" is a noun and "to my country" is a prepositional phrase modifying it.

So to explain why "to visit to my country" is wrong, I guess we have to say that the verb "visit" takes as its direct object the place visited.  Thus it should be "my country"—the place visited—and not "to my country".

Answer (score -2):

The first sentence is correct.

The second sentence is wrong.

They are definitely not both correct.

Comment: The first is usual but you need to provide evidence why "to visit to a country" is incorrect (rather than uncommon or unidiomatic); note that "visit with" is grammatical.